# How to find a quadratic equation given three points, two on the x-axis?

Tags: quadratics, word-problem

Find the quadratic equation for a parabola that passes through $$(1,0) (5,0) (0,10)$$

To do this I turned it into 
$$ x = 1 $$
$$ x = 5 $$
and then into 
$$(x-1)(x-5)$$
after you multiply everything it turns into
$$Y = a(x^2-6x+5)$$
Now My question is how would I find A?
Do i plug in the given y and x point than it would turn into 
$$ 10 = a(5^2 - 6(5) + 5)$$
$$ 10 = a(25 - 30 + 5)$$
$$ 10= a(0)?$$
Is this how you find ***a***?
How would you do this?

Comment: your method looks good up till the end.  You know the curve passes through $(0,10)$ so plug in $x=0$ to see $10=y(0)=a(0^2-6^*0+5)=5a\implies a=2$

Comment: Ohh okay thanks

Answer (score 3):

Our parabola has at most two zeros, that we know, so it is $p(x) = a(x-1)(x-5)$. Now put in the last point you get $p(0) = a(-1)(-5) = 10$ thus $a=2$.

$p(x) = 2(x-1)(x-5) = 2x^2 -12x + 10$.